# While loop with semicolon

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

What does this instruction do? And what is the use of a semicolon with the while loop?

> while (scanf("%s", &s[strlen(s)]) == 1);

I'm working on a program to check whether a string is a panagram or not.
Here is the complete code:

> int main() {

```
char s[100];
while (scanf("%s", &s[strlen(s)]) == 1);
char big[26] = {0};
char small[26] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') {
        small[s[i] - 'a'] = 1;
    }
    else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') {
        big[s[i] - 'A'] = 1;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (!(big[i] == 1 || small[i] == 1)) {
        printf("not pangram");
        return 0;
    }
}

printf("pangram");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: what is the size of `s`? Just asking...

Comment: @SouravGhosh i have declared the array as char s[100];

Comment: Nobody, including the author of this code, knows how it makes any sense.

Comment: Please read a C book. You are asking us to tutor you.

Comment: Why are you asking this ? Is it homework ? Just curious.

Comment: What do you think it does?  If you did not write it, where did you find it?

Comment: 'i have declared the array as char s[100]' so, 'strlen(s)]' is UB, then.

Comment: It is much worse than just overwriting the null terminator. The code says "store a whole string at the address of character number strlen(s)". Not only will it destroy the null terminator and crash & burn in the next lap of the loop because of that, but it will possibly write out of bounds too.

Comment: What null terminator?  The question lacks sufficient context to ensure that there is any null terminator:(

Comment: @MartinJames `strlen` requires a null terminator to be present in advance, or it will crash & burn.

Comment: I have updated the question.. thanks for your comments!

Comment: @GayathriRavi If that is your update, this code invokes UB. `s` must be terminated before entering that while-loop. it isn't.

Comment: @GayathriRavi thanks!  The UB is now clear.

Comment: @Lundin yes, your'e right and, guess what... :)

Comment: Well that's some truly awful code right there. I really hope this is some beginner's code and not something you got from a teacher or book?

Answer (score 5):

`strlen(s)` returns the length of the string (supposing that it is, in fact, a properly-terminated string).

`s[strlen(s)]` therefore designates the string's terminating null byte.

`&s[strlen(s)]` is therefore a pointer to the string's terminator, or, equivalently, to `s`'s zero-length tail substring.

`scanf("%s", &s[strlen(s)])` thus attempts to scan a whitespace-delimited string from the standard input into the tail of `s`.  If `s` has sufficient unused space and the input is indeed available then this will likely succeed.  If it does, then `scanf()` returns `1`, the number of input fields successfully scanned.

If the end of the file is detected before any non-whitespace is scanned, however, then `scanf()` will return zero without adding anything to `s`.

Thus, each time the `while` condition `(scanf("%s", &s[strlen(s)]) == 1)` is tested, it attempts to append the next string from standard input to the end of `s`.

The loop body is an empty statement (the `;`).  That does nothing, so the overall loop just tests the loop condition repeatedly until it evaluates to false.  Provided that `s` is initially a terminated string and that it has enough space, that has the overall side effect of concatenating standard input, less all whitespace, into `s`.  If those provisos are not satisfied, however, the behavior is undefined.

Inasmuch as you do nothing to ensure that `s` is initially terminated, you are at grave risk of UB (though whether the behavior is defined is in fact indeterminate).  Additionally, your program is highly susceptible to a buffer overrun, as it scans user-provided input into a fixed-size buffer without verifying that sufficient space is available.

Comment: That would probably be right, except for the UB.

Comment: @MartinJames, when I first wrote the answer, it was not established that there was any UB.  I have now updated the answer to be predicated on `s` being terminated.  It is already predicated on not overrunning the bounds of `s`.  Do you see any other basis for UB?

Answer (score 3):

```
while(1);
```

is the same as

```
while(1)
{
  // Nothing
}
```

For what your specific while condition does, see the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings are arrays of characters terminated by the null character (0), or they used to be when char was a single byte. :-)

```
  s[strlen(s)]    always zero 
  &s[strlen(s)]   a pointer to zero
```

The scanf call will read a string from stdin, and write it to the address you passed in.

```
 scanf("%s", pointer);

 // does this...

 *pointer = "input string";
```

Since you passed in the address of the last byte of this string, it will overwrite the current end-of-string.

In other words, the code:

- Reads a string from stdin.
- **Appends it to s**
- Assumes that the area of memory allocated to s is large enough to hold whatever the user types in (which it never would be, so you can always crash the code by pressing a key down and holding it).

Comment: Although not (ever) required to be so, C `char` is still eight bits in every modern implementation I know or ever expect to see.

Comment: Thanks, that's strangely comforting...

Answer (score 0):

It's UB.  It was implied UB before you added in all the code because you did not demonstrate that 's' was securely null-terminated.  After adding in the code, it was clearly and explicitly UB since you demonstrated that s was not securely null-terminated.

Comment: could you define UB please?

Comment: If you want to be technical here, the contents of an uninitialized automatic variable are *indeterminate*, therefore it is indeterminate whether the code has defined behavior.  Not that that's any better, of course.

Comment: lol i remember now. So glad variables are initialized to zeros these days :-)

Comment: @buffjape: How do you figure that variables *are* initialized "these days"?

Comment: In C# they seems to be always filled with zero bytes (0, null, false) etc. They couldn't do that in the '70s and '80s, it would have been too slow.

Comment: @buffjape, C# is not C.  Although it has similar syntax, its semantics are rather different from C's.  It was created as a competitor to Java, and it has a lot more similarities there.

Comment: Thanks. I'm an old C programmer who now uses C#. Enjoying the retro questions :-)

Comment: The question is clearly tagged C, the char array 's' is declared with automatic storage and is NOT initialized to anything.

Comment: Sure but the question is about the while loop :-)